# Cannot find files on system folders on jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I cant seem to find my system folders on jupyter, i can just find three folders.Im new to jupyter, any help will be appreciated.
I am running windows 10. Current jupyter version is 6.0.1. and i launched it through Anaconda.

[image: pic]

Comment: Try looking for a hidden (dot) folder .jupyter

Comment: You can only see the folder (and subfolders) of where you launched jupyter from, are you looking for parent folders?